# External variable in callback for chunk()

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to implement search in Laravel. I want to search on models. Since there can be many records in the database, I am trying the `chunk` function.

```
public function searchLeads($param)
    {
        $results = array();

        // get all leads
        Lead::chunk(100, function($leads) use ($results, $param) {
            // search in name
            $results = array_merge($results, $this->repository->searchInName($leads, $param));

            // search in email
            $results = array_merge($results, $this->repository->searchInEmail($leads, $param));

           // and so on ...
    }

    // eliminate duplicates
    $collection = collect($results);
    $collection = $collection->unique();

    $results = $collection->all();

    dd($results);
    // return $results;
}
```

Note: The `searchIn`... functions return array of results and are working as expected.

When I try the above code, I get an empty array. So I changed the following line (added a reference `&` to `$results`).

```
Lead::chunk(100, function($leads) use (&$results, $param) {
```

Now I get the expected output.

Am I doing this the correct way? Have I stumbled upon the right solution, or am I missing something that might introduce bugs in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution after reading a bit about `php closures`. My real worry was that I am not using the `$results` array correctly.

But after reading [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), I know I am doing it correctly.

Please note that I am aware of `where` clause and it's usage would be much more efficient here. But that's not what I was trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You managed to bypass the query builder, which could have implemented this as a trivial, single query on the backing database, and instead managed to emulate that query in an very inefficient manner yourself.

```
// get all leads
Lead::chunk(100, function($leads) use ($results, $param) {
    // search in name
    $results = array_merge($results, $this->repository->searchInName($leads, $param));

    // search in email
    $results = array_merge($results, $this->repository->searchInEmail($leads, $param));

    // and so on ...
}
```

This effectively causes 2 additional queries to the database for each 100 results in the `Lead` model. This might still work reasonably in your test environment where you have at most a few dozen leads registered, but will crawl to a halt in production as the number of leads increases with time.

Even worse, it requires you to stream all existing `Lead` instances through PHP, even if they are not even part of the final result set.

Comment: So what do you suggest? If you are suggesting using `where clause`, let me tell you that's not possible. I am not strictly searching on database columns. There are derived values and related records that need to be searched; hence those `searchIn...`functions.

Comment: @linuxartisan Searching in related records and derived values is what your relational database is good at. Hence I doubt that you couldn't state your query in a compact form using the query builder. Maybe you should add the source for `searchInName` and `searchInEmail`, as well as the `Lead` model to your original question, as they appear to be part of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The chunk call should replace the get call - it is designed to work on the pre-get() query builder object.

```
means you need to change Lead::chunk to
$leads = Lead::orderBy('created','desc');
$leads->chunk(100, function($leads) use ($results, $param) {
            // search in name
            $results = array_merge($results, $this->repository->searchInName($leads, $param));

            // search in email
            $results = array_merge($results, $this->repository->searchInEmail($leads, $param));

           // and so on ...
    }
```

and for more
do not need of method $collection->all()

```
$collection = collect($results);
$collection = $collection->unique();  
$return  = $collection->all(); 
dd($return);
```

Comment: please check the edited answer, reference 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38551313/1363245

Comment: `$collection->all()` is for converting the collection to array.